React native expo build failed with comileReleaseJavaWithJavac and CompileReleaseKotlin incompatible?
I am using a React native Expo project to build app via EAS and build works .  As soon as I updated to expo 50. Build process failed for android version with below errors .
Any help would be highly appreciated .
Error during build process
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-permissions:compileReleaseKotlin'.


'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 17) and 'compileReleaseKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
`

dependency file
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "11.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "btoa": "^1.2.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "country-data": "^0.0.31",
    "expo": "^50.0.15",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~12.9.3",
    "expo-camera": "^14.1.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~16.0.8",
    "expo-localization": "~14.8.3",
    "expo-location": "~16.5.5",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.10.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.24.12",
    "i18n-js": "^3.9.2",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "make-plural": "^7.3.0",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.38",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-maps": "1.10.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-textarea": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-webview": "13.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}


Build using expo build process using EAS
eas build --platform android   --profile preview 
